# Uploading Django app to Python anywhere

Tags: python, mysql, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm currently trying to upload my django app to pythonanywhere and i keep running into errors with my wsgi application, it says "sys" is not defined. I have correctly followed all the steps in the manual that pythonanywhere provides, yet it is still not working. I want to know if anyone has successfully uploaded a django app with pythonanywhere and how he/she got it done; or if there are better alternatives i can explore. Thanks. I would be waiting for an answer.

Comment: create an AWS account and then try to deploy your app on it.

Comment: if sys is not imported, this is main lib from python, so you have problem on your python installation, check python --version, or maybe you forgot to activate your virtualenv

Comment: If you're getting an error saying that `sys` is not define, you're probably just missing `import sys` at the top of the code where you're using it.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonanywhere advice to set up a virtual environment, in which you install all dependancies. Have you done so?